# Replacing missing values by searching dataframe for those values by matching

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe with ~ 500,000 observations, some of the cols have blanks, e.g. a missing name. However the names correspond with an ID, sometimes the name or ID are both there, but sometimes one or the other is missing. Is there a way to search through the df, find and match the missing data

So in this simple example

```
structure(list(Names = c("Jon", "Al", "Phil", "Sarah", "Jon", 
" "), ID = c(12, 14, 16, 18, 12, 14)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))


df

  Names ID
1   Jon 12
2    Al 14
3  Phil 16
4 Sarah 18
5   Jon 12
6       14
```

I know that 14 matches with `Al` So I could replace the blank on row 6 with Al.
But how can I do this on a larger scale with multiple missing values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `ID` have only a single unique 'Names' - do a group by 'ID' and replace the 'Names'  that are blank (`""`) with the first 'Names'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(Names = trimws(Names)) %>%
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate(Names = replace(Names, Names == "", 
           first(Names[Names != ""]))) %>% 
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  Names    ID
  <chr> <dbl>
1 Jon      12
2 Al       14
3 Phil     16
4 Sarah    18
5 Jon      12
6 Al       14
```

---

Another option is to replace the `""` to `NA` and then use `fill` to replace the missing values by 'ID' with the non-NA adjacent Names

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(Names = na_if(trimws(Names), "")) %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   fill(Names, .direction = 'downup') %>%
   ungroup
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  Names    ID
  <chr> <dbl>
1 Jon      12
2 Al       14
3 Phil     16
4 Sarah    18
5 Jon      12
6 Al       14
```

Comment: Thanks for this, out of interest why do you add the `trimws`, some of the rows in my df will have spaces, but I don't think that will be an issue

Comment: @McMahok that was because `trimws` removes the leading/laggging spaces.  In your case, there was `" "` instead of `""`, thus trimws changes it to `""`, which is more normalized in case there are `" ",` or `"      "` etc, thus we have to replace only a single blank element instead of multiple ones

Comment: ah ok thanks for clarification